# Timeout with file_get_contents and curl

Tags: curl, fopen

Im having a problem with file_get_contents and curl,

(unable to connect to ...)

Even to google...

Curl is active and fopen too ... Any idea?

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    return curl_exec ($ch);
}
echo curl("http://site.com/");
```

Comment: Curl error: Couldn't resolve host 'google.com'

Comment: Is there any change that this be a problem with DNS?

Answer (score 0):

http://srv14.baixarpremium.net/test.php

A simple

```
function curl($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if ($data === false) { echo curl_error($ch); }
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

echo curl("http://baixarpremium.net/");
```

Takes several minutes...

But sometimes goes fast... So please release the page more than 1 time to see the problem...

I put a script t see the time that the script run ...

Look at the result

Elapsed time: 119.17127 secs. Memory usage: 0.75Mb

oO

Just to open 1 page...

And you access http://srv14.baixarpremium.net/

The script runs fast just with a Header to baixarpremium.net/gerador/

Without the curl it goes very fast..`enter code here`